# How should I analyze this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The following is a line from *Wordsmith* by Pamela Arlov.

> **For all we try to show our kids and tell them how we believe people should act, how we hope they will act**, it still comes as a shock and a pleasure — a relief, frankly — when they do something that suggests they understand.

I think the first part of the bold typed phrase should be analyzed as

For all (that_i) we try to show our kids [_i]

But, the second part

tell them how we believe people should act, how we hope they will act

also have to have a gap [_i] in it for the whole of the bald typed phrase to be an adverbial. But, I can't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“For all that” as subordinating conjunction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/536001/for-all-that-as-subordinating-conjunction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no relative construction here. *For all* allows the clause that follows, which contains a coordination:

> we
>
> try to show our kids [how we believe people should act, how we hope
> they will act]
>
> tell them [how we believe people should act, how we hope they will
> act]

*For all* here serves a similar function to *although*, the whole phrase being a concessive adjunct. It also carries a meaning similar to an adjunct of degree/frequency as in *very much/often*. We could paraphrase it as:

> Although we **frequently/very much** try to...

Similar examples:

> For all he found Anne-Sylvie frustrating, he also found her attractive
> and that bothered him. (Blind Justice, S.N. Lewitt, Ace Books 1991)
>
> For all he was so young, he had seen something of the world, and had
> already made notable friends. (Colonel Washington, Woodrow Wilson,
> Harpers: March, 1896)
>
> For all he cares about the money, he says, he would give it to the cop
> on the corner, if that would serve any purpose. (THE TERRIBLE-TEMPERED
> DR. BARNES; McCardle, Carl W.; Saturday Evening Post: 3/21/1942)

Comment: thank you. I didn't know that "for all" can work as a conjunction. Could you please give me another example!

Comment: thank you for examples. Let me ask one more thing. Why does "all" add the meaning of concession to a phrase such as those, or "For all his faults" in "For all his faults, he’s a kind-hearted old soul."?

Comment: Good question. The dictionaries that do list _for all_ have it as an idiom, so it's probably best analyzed as an inseparable item that has a special meaning not deducible from the standard functions of its separate parts, an analysis that The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language agrees with as it lists it in a category with 'for fear' and 'on condition'.

Comment: Which of your answers is the duplicate?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Good catch, upon consideration this is the better one. I've deleted the other.

Comment: @DW256 +1 for a nice answer. Just this small question I have: Would it make any difference to say that _For all_ serves a similar function as _In spite of/Despite_ and that the writer has resorted to ellipsis here: _In spite of/Despite_ [all that] we try to... That makes sense too, right?

Comment: 'For all' means 'in spite of the fact that' (followed by two independent clauses) _or_ 'despite' when followed by NP + independent clause.